# PHP file upload mistake

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I have a form and I am trying to move the file to "files folder" but somehow i fail. The file is not being moved to the folder.

I know my code might be wrong, I am a begGiner so please be kind to me and if you could tell me what to put where I would be really grateful. Thank you.

```
 $yourname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['yourname']);
        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $folder="uploads/";

    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case
    
    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO userfiles (yourname, file) VALUES ('$yourname', '$final_file')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    header('Location: http://pokus2.envi-help.cz/cestak.php');
    exit;
    } else{


        echo "ERROR: not added " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
    // close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You should try actually moving the file at some point. http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: what and where exactly should i put it please?